# Access violation when accessing random vector element

Tags: c++

I have a vector of integers, and want to randomly access one of its elements. Here is a minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

class Random
{
private:
    const int N = 8;
    std::vector<int> data;
    std::mt19937 randomGenerator;

public:
    void Reset(int seed = 0) {
        data.resize(N + 1);
        if(seed) { this->randomGenerator.seed(seed); }
    }

    void UpdateVector(int delta) {
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniformBuffer(1, N);
        /*unsigned*/ int randomIndex = uniformBuffer( randomGenerator );
        data[randomIndex] += delta;
    }
};

int main() {
    Random rnd;
    rnd.Reset();
    rnd.UpdateVector(1);
    return 0;
}
```

This works perfectly in Debug mode in Microsoft Visual C++ 2017. But when I run the program in Release mode, it crashes with an Access Violation. A quick look at the generated assembly code shows some magic going on, in which the `int` index is extended (with sign) to a `size_t`, then a weird value (I think it was `0xffff0004`) is added - which is indeed not a valid index anymore!

I managed to fix the bug by uncommenting the 'unsigned' modifier in the declaration of `randomIndex`, but I am very curious why. Is this a bug in the compiler I'm using (a quick search didn't turn up anything plausible) or is there a misunderstanding on my part?

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with your code (except not actually getting around to seeding), but in my mind this would be more than a substantial compiler bug so I remain suspicious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While investigating your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49241407/access-violation-when-accessing-random-vector-element) yesterday, which was closed and you deleted right before reposting it here, the problem is a bug with the Microsoft optimizer for 64 bit code.

When taking the result from `uniform_int_distribution<int>` and passing it as a `size_t` value to vector's `operator[]`, an adjustment factor used internally to "convert signed ranges to unsigned ranges and vice versa" is being retained outside the distribution class, and scaled for the array access, causing a problem.  Oddly enough, this doesn't happen when converting the result to a `size_t` for display.

This sample demonstrates the problem.

```
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

const int N = 8;
std::mt19937 randomGenerator;

class tester {
public:
    int operator[](size_t idx) const {
        std::cout << "Offset is " << std::hex << idx << "\n";
        return int(idx);
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniformBuffer(1, N);
    std::cout << "Number " << size_t(uniformBuffer(randomGenerator)) << "\n";
    tester t;
    std::cout << "Index " << v[t[uniformBuffer(randomGenerator)]] << "\n";
}
```

Using the 64 bit compiler, compiling with `cl /W4 /MD /EHsc /Ox` the output is

```
Number 5
Offset is ffffffff00000007
Index 7
```

The use of `v` is necessary.  If it is omitted, the offset passed to `tester` is 7.

Comment: If I take your example, and compile the same way you did, I get the following output: `Number 5|Offset is 7|Index 7` (where `|` stands for new-line).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius You need to build it with the 64 bit compiler.  The 32 bit compiler doesn't have the problem.  (I'm using "Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.12.25830.2 for x64")

Comment: Thanks. After some more digging it seems that the bug _was_ actually known and apparently it's been fixed in version 15.5.4. Installing that now, we'll see if that helps. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0df4e317-463e-4217-832c-da237aaa6810/stdvector-operator-compiler-optimization-problem?forum=vcgeneral

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Well.. I **am** using the 64-bit compiler: "Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.12.25834 for x64" (note, that the version of my compiler is newer - so maybe the issue was already fixed).